# Help Identifying Parts Bags - Technic with a lot of different colors

Tags: set-identification

Can anyone figure out what set these two unopened bags belong to? The loose parts were in a ziplock bag along with the unopened so they MIGHT be part of the same set.

[image: 3 bags]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All of the pictured polybags show these bricks are part of the same set - [BOOST Creative Toolbox (17101)](https://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?S=17101-1)

[image]

Comment: I'm guessing that the OP is missing the parts from that set that allow you to make an actual robot that you can control with an app on your mobile device?

Comment: @nick012000 Based on posted pictures OP has only 3 polybags out of 11. Most obvious missing parts are the electronics, threads and Dark Azure elements.